# Abbreviations for weekdays

Tags: kanji, word-order, abbreviations

I was studying Japanese weekdays and I found something interesting: you can use abbreviations such us ゲッすい (月水) to indicate both Monday and Wednesday or  木土 pron. どぼく to indicate Thursday and Saturday. When can you use them? And how many of them are? Is there an order of the kanji when you use them (can I say すいゲ instead of ゲッすい)?

Comment: 木土 must be もくど (because 木 is もく and 土 is ど) and 土木(どぼく) is also existing word which has completely different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of abbreviations are used to indicate two or more days of general week or certain week. That is, 月水金(げっすいきん) can mean either "Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays (in general)" or "Monday, Wednesday and Friday (of certain week)" according to the context.

In such abbreviations, the order of kanji generally follows the actual order of days. (e.g. people say 月水(げっすい) but not 水月 because Monday comes before Wednesday) I am not sure how to form this kind of abbreviations when Sunday involved, but it is safe to say that consecutive days are represented in that order (e.g. people say 土日月(どにちげつ) but not 日月土 nor 月土日).

Comment: 土日月 would be read [どー]{HL}[にち]{HL}[げつ]{HL}, not どにちげつ. Each day is said separately in some sense, so the ど gets elongated to match the meter. Same with 火 when used in this construction.